# How to overload all math functions simultaneously for a class of numerical arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, overloading

I have designed a class of numerical array called `ndarray`, which basically contains a double array member `double *data`. I have overloaded the math function `double log(double)` such that it is a friend of the class and when called with an input `ndarray` object, returns an object of `ndarray` of the same size as the input array with its elements the logarithm of the input array.
My question is, since I don't want to rewrite the same code for ALL the mathematical functions of the form `double fun(double)`, how can I overload all of them simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to add a member to your ndarray class for applying a function to each element and returning the result.  This doesn't overload all the math functions, but lets you do things like `ndarray.apply(sin)`.  Perhaps something like the following (untested):

```
class myNdarray
{
  template <typename T>
  myNdarray apply(T func) const
  {
    myNdarray ret(*this);
    for (auto& elm: ret) elm = func(elm);
    return ret;
  }
};
```

In the above I use C++11 `auto` and I make a few assumptions about how your type behaves, but you could implement this without C++11.  You could also remove the template type `T` and instead specify an explicit type (perhaps a function only taking a single double and returning a double would be safer).

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of `std::transform`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way of doing so, as C++ does not support covariant inheritance or aggregation.

You can do it with some advanced `boost::mpl` magic, but I suggest just using `std::valarray` instead. Not only it appears to be exactly what you need, it also features some neat delayed-execution optimizations. The only drawback is it has limited amount of math methods available, so check the full description first to make sure it has all that you need.